# Does "commit <action>" always imply a negative moral judgement?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

The word "commit" has a couple of uses: "to commit (oneself) to X", or "to commit X". The former seems to generally imply commitment to doing something good, while the latter seems to generally be negative.

Examples:

- commit a crime
- commit murder
- commit suicide<sup>*</sup>
- commit a felony
- commit treason

Is there any case, contemporary or archaic, where this structure is used without negative connotations? Why, historically, did this pattern develop?

<sub>*This example is somewhat anomalous, since in modern usage, though negative, it may not imply a moral judgment.</sub>

Comment: A Google search for "commit an act of kindness" certainly turns up quite a few hits. This could be seen as a reaction against the negative thrust the verb usually carries when used in the 'carry out' sense. Earlier, I'd have said it was merely a tongue-in-cheek usage. / As I estimate the probability of finding supporting evidence for these views less than 1%, I'll not look for any, and I'll confinethis response to a 'comment'.

Comment: One can commit funds or other resources to a project.

Comment: I suppose the difference with committing "funds", or committing in a VCS (for programmers) is that those uses involve committing a thing, not committing an action. E.g. a "crime" is something you do, but "funds" are not.

Comment: Adding _act_ or _deed_ gets you well into positive territory: _commit a charitable, loving, honest act_, but _commit x_ seems fully inhabited by sins, crimes, and other negatives.

Comment: I'll be sure to commit whatever answer you select as the best to memory. Hopefully, that won't be a bad thing. Should I be committed to a mental institution for thinking that? Wait, if I'm committed to a mental institution, does that make me bad or make me getting treatment bad? I wait with baited breath to find out.

Answer (score 3):

The *OED* does apply an entire branch (**II**) of the word **commit** to "perpetrating" something negative.

> To do something wrong; to perpetrate.

This branch seems to encapsulate most of the common examples cited here where the term carries a moral judgment, such as *commit suicide* or *commit a felony*.

In its etymology notes, the *OED* explains the development of this branch:

> In classical Latin the expression *committere legiones* ‘to commit troops’ gave rise to *committere pugnam* ‘to join battle‘, and from this developed the sense ‘to begin, undertake’ which in turn acquired a pejorative sense ‘to perpetrate’ (compare Branch **II**.).

This pejorative sense dominates uses of the word in this structure *to commit [action]*, even to the extent that it can sometimes distort other senses that are inherently non-pejorative.  An example is the once common phrase **commit matrimony**, meaning *to get married*.

The *OED* provides a phrasal definition with numerous citations for "commit matrimony," though, amusingly, some of the citations acknowledge the latent pejorative sense:

> ‘You shouldn't say this young couple **“committed” matrimony.**’ ‘Why not?’ ‘It isn't good taste. **You talk as if they had done something wrong**.’ [emphasis added]

- **1903**   *Ohio Law Bulletin* 25 May 216/2

Answer (score 0):

The usage of [commit](https://www.etymonline.com/word/commit) in reference to negative, reprehensible actions is derived from the Latin usage of “committere” from which the English commit is derived:

> The evolution of the modern range of meanings in English is not entirely clear. ***Sense of "to perpetrate (a crime), do, perform (especially something reprehensible)" was ancient in Latin; in English it is attested from mid-15c.***  Meaning "consign (someone) to custody (of prison, a mental institution, etc.) by official warrant" is from early 15c.

(Etymonline)

Note that the same usage with reference to negative actions is common also in other languages like ***French [commetre](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/commettre/17503), Spanish [cometer](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/cometer) and Italian [commettere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/commettere.shtml)*** given their common etymology.

Comment: In software we commit a change when it is finished and added into the main product - not sure if this is always    reprehensible ;-)

Comment: @mgb - yes, not common usage I guess, outside the software jargon. I guess OP is asking about more common usage as in the 3xamples they cited.

Answer (score 0):

As well as matrimony and kindness, acts of bravery are committed.

See http://dariuszgalasinski.com/2018/06/30/silencing-suicide/ for discussion of the positive and negative uses of the word "commit".

Comment: Do you mean "commit kindness" or "commit acts of kindness?"  I found zero Ngram results without "acts" and welcome your findings.